How to call ssh connect fixture in teardown
I want to test some scenarios by executing command through ssh connection. I need the ssh connection fixture to be called second time.
So my scenario is like:
Inside conftest.py file
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")

def get_ssh_connection(vars, logger):

    ssh = SshClient(ip=vars["ip"],
                    port=vars["port"],
                    user=vars["username"],
                    passwd=vars["pw"])
    ssh.connect()
    yield ssh
    ssh.close()

Inside test script:
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def setup_teardown(self, list):
    self.ssh.exec_cmd(f"mv {file} {newfile}")  # rename file
    self.restartDevice()  #ssh connection closed
    yield
    **self.ssh.exec_cmd**(f"mv {newfile} {file}") #restore file
    self.restartDevice()

How to enable this ssh connection (highlighted one) after restartdevice since ssh connection is a fixture as session?

I don't see the relationship between  get_ssh_connection() and setup_teardown() making it hard understand what going on.

get_ssh_connection() is the fixture inside conftest.py file and setup_teardown() is the test case class fixture.So when we are rebooting(restart) the device, ssh disconnected. then onward there is no ssh connection so how we can use the get_ssh_connection() after 1st restart of the device to get the ssh connection.

I still don't understand how everything fit together. I don't see any test, I don't see anything at all which uses the fixture get_ssh_connection. In order to help, I have to understand the problem. Right now, I don't.

My bad. Can you please give me some examples how can we get  the ssh connectivity after device restart so that we can use the linux commands after that. Since after restart the ssh connectivity is lost(definded in fixture scope=session)

Here is an example which demonstrates this scenario:

Before the tests start, a fixture (ssh_client) will connect to a remote host via ssh.
The fixture then perform some prep works, then reboot
The fixture then keep trying to connect to the remote host until success (meaning the remote host has successfully come online)
At this point, the control will pass to the tests, which can use the ssh_client fixture. I am writing 2 simple tests in this case.
At the end of the session, the fixture will perform some clean up.

Code
# conftest.py
import logging
import time

import paramiko
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def ssh_client():
    """
    Create a ssh client and perform some prep works remotely.
    """
    logging.info("First connection...")
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
    client.connect("192.168.64.18", username="ubuntu")
    logging.info("Connected")

    logging.info("Prep the remote host")
    # Perform prep works here

    logging.info("Reboot the remote host")
    client.exec_command("sudo shutdown -r now")

    logging.info("Second connection...")
    while True:
        try:
            client.connect("192.168.64.18", username="ubuntu")
            logging.info("Connected again")
            break
        except (
            paramiko.SSHException,
            paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError,
        ):
            time.sleep(3)

    yield client

    logging.info("Clean up remote host")
    # Do something here to clean up

# test_it.py
import paramiko


def test_user_is_not_root(ssh_client: paramiko.SSHClient):
    _, stdout, _ = ssh_client.exec_command("whoami")
    user = stdout.read().decode().strip()
    assert user != "root"


def test_os_release_exists(ssh_client: paramiko.SSHClient):
    with ssh_client.open_sftp() as sftp:
        sftp.stat("/etc/os-release")  # Will raise if not exist

# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--strict-markers"
log_cli_level = "INFO"
log_cli = true

Notes

The fixture ssh_client is a little long, but I hope straight forward
This is a session-scope fixture, so it only perform once.
I use the pyproject.toml file to control the logging level.


Thank you very much for the information. Let me try and update.
